# Image Resizing not working using s3reader

Tags: amazon-s3, image-resizing, imageresizer

I m using Image resizer to resize the amazon images.

I m not getting any errors but i m not also able to resize my image.

I have tried to open the image url directly, it doesn't show any errors there as well.

Also i m using this on visual studio web server so the IIS is not the problem.

I m using MVC and have installed MvcRoutingShim plugin properly.

I m trying to resize the image from height = 600 to height = 100 but it doesn't work.

My Disgnostics output is as under

```
    Image resizer diagnostic sheet      4/2/2013 11:52:23 AM

    2 Issues detected:

    (Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.


    (Warning):  NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.
    Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use


    You are using paid bundles: Cloud Bundle

    Registered plugins:

    ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
    ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
    ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
    ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
    ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
    ImageResizer.Plugins.MvcRoutingShim.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
    ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader.S3Reader

    Configuration:

    <resizer>
      <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
      <plugins>
        <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
        <add name="S3Reader" buckets="refp" />
      </plugins>
    </resizer>


    Accepted querystring keys:

    quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, scale, stretch, crop, cropxunits, cropyunits, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, ignoreicc, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, anchor, dpi, mode, zoom,

    Accepted file extensions:

    bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi,

    Environment information:

    Running Microsoft-IIS/7.5 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 and CLR 4.0.30319.296
    Trust level: Unrestricted
    OS bitness: AMD64
    Executing assembly: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
    IntegratedPipeline: True

    Loaded assemblies:

    mscorlib                                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.296   Info: 4.0.30319.296
    System.Web                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.272   Info: 4.0.30319.272
    System                                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
    System.Core                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
    System.Xml                               Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
    System.Data.SqlXml                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Configuration                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Runtime.Caching                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237   Info: 4.0.30319.237
    System.Web.RegularExpressions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Data                              Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.237   Info: 4.0.30319.237
    System.Numerics                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Transactions                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.EnterpriseServices                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    Microsoft.Build.Framework                Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    Microsoft.JScript                        Assembly: 10.0.0.0        File: 10.0.30319.296  Info: 10.0.30319.296
    System.Web.Mvc                           Assembly: 3.0.0.0         File: 3.0.20105.0
    System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407
    System.Web.WebPages                      Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407
    Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407
    System.Web.WebPages.Razor                Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407
    System.Web.Razor                         Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407
    System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Data.Linq                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Web.Extensions                    Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.272   Info: 4.0.30319.272
    App_Code.2uqj4rtu                        Assembly: 0.0.0.0
    App_global.asax.eogwkngg                 Assembly: 0.0.0.0
    FluentValidation.Mvc                     Assembly: 3.2.0.0         File: 3.2.0.0
    EntityFramework                          Assembly: 4.1.0.0         File: 4.1.10331.0     Info: 4.1.10331.0
    System.Data.Entity                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Xml.Linq                          Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Runtime.Serialization             Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly Assembly: 0.0.0.0
    System.Data.OracleClient                 Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    FluentValidation                         Assembly: 3.2.0.0         File: 3.2.0.0
    Cassette                                 Assembly: 2.0.0.17974     File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
    EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EntityFramework Assembly: 1.0.0.0
    System.ServiceModel.Activation           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
    System.Runtime.DurableInstancing         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.ServiceModel                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
    SMDiagnostics                            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Xaml.Hosting                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    Elmah                                    Assembly: 1.2.13605.0     File: 1.2.13605.2128
    Cassette.Aspnet                          Assembly: 2.0.0.17975     File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
    Microsoft.CSharp                         Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Web.Services                      Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Drawing                           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
    System.IdentityModel                     Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1001  Info: 4.0.30319.1001
    System.ServiceModel.Web                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.233   Info: 4.0.30319.233
    System.Activities                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.ServiceModel.Activities           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.WorkflowServices                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Data.DataSetExtensions            Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Web.DynamicData                   Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Web.ApplicationServices           Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    AjaxMin                                  Assembly: 4.60.4609.17023
    AWSSDK                                   Assembly: 1.5.16.1        File: 1.5.16.1
    Cassette.Views                           Assembly: 2.0.0.17975     File: 2.0.0.0         Info: 2.0.0
    ImageResizer                             Assembly: 3.3.3.123       File: 3.3.3.123       Info: 3-3-3  Commit: c368317
    ImageResizer.Mvc                         Assembly: 3.3.3.123       File: 3.3.3.123       Info: 3-3-3  Commit: c368317
    ImageResizer.Plugins.S3Reader            Assembly: 3.3.3.123       File: 3.3.3.123       Info: 3-3-3  Commit: c368317
    librets-dotnet                           Assembly: 0.0.0.0
    LinqKit                                  Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.0.0
    Newtonsoft.Json                          Assembly: 4.5.0.0         File: 4.5.3.14814
    System.Web.Abstractions                  Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Web.Helpers                       Assembly: 1.0.0.0         File: 1.0.20105.407
    System.Web.Routing                       Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
    System.Web.Mobile                        Assembly: 4.0.0.0         File: 4.0.30319.1     Info: 4.0.30319.1
```

The url for which i m trying to resize the image is https://s3.amazonaws.com/refp/property/802/802_1.jpeg?height=100.

Please help.

Source: http://imageresizing.net/plugins/s3reader

Comment: Please move your answer to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Just change the URL from

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/refp(bucketname)/property(foldername)/802(foldername)/802_1.jpeg?height=100
```

To

```
http://youraspnetserver/s3/refp(bucketname)/property(foldername)/802(foldername)/802_1.jpeg?height=100
```

The URL always needs to point to your .NET server, not the S3 blob, as Amazon's S3 servers are just static file servers, and can't do anything dynamic.

Comment: Thanks but i have already solved that pls have a look at the update i've made in my question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In the future, use the "Answer Your Own Question" button to log an answer - you are not supposed to simply edit the question.